# Error in Hadoop installation

Tags: java, python, apache, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I am trying to install `Hadoop` on fedora machine by seeing [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.15.2/quickstart.html)

1. Installed java (and verified whether java exists with `java -version`) and it exists
2. I had ssh installed(since it is linux)
3. Downloaded latest version `hadoop 1.0.4` from [here](http://apache.techartifact.com/mirror/hadoop/common/hadoop-1.0.4/)

I have followed the process shown in installation tutorial(link given above) as below

```
$ mkdir input 
$ cp conf/*.xml input 
$ bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples.1.0.4.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
```

Then i had got the following error, which i am unable to understand

```
sh-4.2$ bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.0.4.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
12/10/31 16:14:35 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
12/10/31 16:14:35 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
12/10/31 16:14:35 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 8
12/10/31 16:14:35 INFO mapred.JobClient: Cleaning up the staging area file:/tmp/hadoop-thomas/mapred/staging/shivakrishnab-857393825/.staging/job_local_0001
12/10/31 16:14:35 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:thomas cause:java.io.IOException: Not a file: file:/home/local/thomas/Hadoop/hadoop-1.0.4/input/conf
java.io.IOException: Not a file: file:/home/local/thomas/Hadoop/hadoop-1.0.4/input/conf
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:989)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:981)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$600(JobClient.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:850)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:850)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:824)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1261)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.Grep.run(Grep.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.Grep.main(Grep.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

Can anyone let me know whats wrong with my machine/or code, what to do to avoid this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, ssh preinstalled doesn't mean it's configured. you need both ssh and sshd and a keypair. it should be passwordless, 'preferably'.just make sure that you are able to ssh to host without any error.also, make sure that all the hadoop daemons are running fine.it would be better if we could have a look at your error logs. i have written the complete procedure to configure hadoop [here](http://cloudfront.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-configure-hadoop.html), in case you need any help.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to JVM and there is known issue regarding file permission in Hadoop(Some Versions)..
so check this link :

```
       https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-7682
```

Hope this helps